Is the language {a^m b^n a^n b^m | m, n >= 1} context free?
Based on my understanding, I ended up at the following grammar:
A -> bAa | λ
S -> aSb | A | λ

Is it sufficient to say the above language $L = \{a^m b^n a^n b^m \mid m, n \ge 1\}$ context free? If not, could you please explain why?
EDIT:
Case 1: If m, n >= 1
A -> bAa | ba
S -> aSb | A

Case 2: If m, n >= 0
A -> bAa | λ
S -> aSb | A | λ


Your grammar can generate the word $\lambda$ and the word $ab$, which are not in the language.

The following context-free grammar recognizes/generates $L = \{a^m b^n a^n b^m | m, n \ge 1\}$. Start symbol is S (ε is empty string/word).
S -> aAb
A -> bBa | aAb
B -> bBa | ε

Also the following context-free grammar recognizes/generates $L_0 = \{a^m b^n a^n b^m | m, n \ge 0\}$
S -> A
A -> bBa | aAb | ε
B -> bBa | ε

